# How do I make the bot show how much he deleted the message? [!clear]

Tags: discord.py

I am not an experienced developer, and I would like to ask a question how to make the bot count how much he deleted the command message *!clear*

```
@Client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=None):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(amount))
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0x00b8f5)
    embed.set_author(name="• Сообщение были удалены!")
    embed.add_field(name="Кол-во:",
                value=f"{counter}",
                inline=True)
    #============================
    embed.add_field(name="Статус:",
                value="Выполнено.",
                inline=True)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=5.0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption, to declare some sort of variable, is correct here.

You can approach this in a pretty simple way:

1. Define `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)`
2. Get the `len` of your definition

**Here's the full code:**

```py
async def clear(ctx, amount: int = None):
    if amount is None:
        await ctx.send("Please specify the number of messages to delete.")
        return

    deleted_messages = await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    counter = len(deleted_messages) - 1

    # Embed with the {counter} "variable"
```

- Here we define `await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)` as `deleted_messages` and get the `len` of it in the next step
- `-1` is here used to not count the command that was deleted as well
- I also changed `amount` to an integer to be on the safe side
- If no number is given, we simply give out an error